# How python object memory works for int less than -5 and greater 256

Tags: python

In my understanding, all things in python are object and some of them per-allocate memory to them (for int the range is from -5 to 256). 
 My question is if the address not per-allocate, does it create in fly?

for example:

```
print id(256)
a = 256
print id(a)

36609008
36609008
```

this example indicates variable a is referring the object 256's memory, thus they have same address.

```
print id(300)
a = 300
print id(a)

106711544
106708304
```

for the example above:

1. does python create two objects? (it seems yes)
2. why -5 to 256?
3. would those per-allocated object be reused to create new objects?

Comment: For the CPython implementation at least, yes it does.

Comment: As you can see from the object `id`s, yes, python has created two objects.

Comment: @tdelaney so further question is why -5 to 256?

Comment: The small integers are preallocated for speed. Other integer objects are allocated in blocks and may be reassigned different values as ref counts go to zero (meaning it has no user and can be recycled for a new integer).

Comment: In the C implementation, all objects share a common header. Integers can't be different because then they would need to be special-cased throughout any C Extensions that use them.

Comment: @tdelaney I agree. For the speed part, why -5 to 256? based on what?

Comment: Based on a wild guess, mostly. I don't have the details of the implementation but I bet it has something to do with the size of the blocks allocated.

Comment: @tdelaney haha, that is the part I could not figure out. I think the block size is from 5 to 512b.